# Order of args to an HMAC?

Tags: encryption, hmac, trusted-vs-untrusted

If I send the following response more than once to an untrusted party:

```
{c, v, HMAC(c + v)}
```

where c is the same value from response to response.
where v varies from response to response.
where + is a concatenation.

Does having the constant as the start of the HMAC input "weaken" the HMAC?

Is it safer to compute the HMAC with the varying argument first:

```
{c, v, HMAC(v + c)}
```

or perhaps doesn't matter?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a cryptography question unrelated to programming. [crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) may be a more appropriate venue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter. HMAC is designed specifically to address prefix attacks, among others.